# How to rewrite from new array method to literal array method in Javascript

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

Hi I have captured the data from a google spreadsheet to a new array like this

```
$.getJSON("https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1IoNqeReOPKNFrYMlK2rnJVuMaLeAgnZneLbKYSQ7bs4/od6/public/values?alt=json", function(data) {
      //$.getJSON("http://cors.io/spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1IoNqeReOPKNFrYMlK2rnJVuMaLeAgnZneLbKYSQ7bs4/od6/public/values?alt=json", function(data) {
    var len = data.feed.entry.length;
    for (var i=0; i<len; i++) {
      //first row "title" column
      resultData[i]=new Array(9);
      resultData[i][1]=data.feed.entry[i].gsx$constituency.$t;
      resultData[i][2]=data.feed.entry[i].gsx$winner2010.$t;
      resultData[i][3]=data.feed.entry[i].gsx$winningparty.$t;
      resultData[i][4]=data.feed.entry[i].gsx$candidatename1.$t;
      resultData[i][5]=data.feed.entry[i].gsx$party1.$t;
      resultData[i][6]=data.feed.entry[i].gsx$candidatename2.$t;
      resultData[i][7]=data.feed.entry[i].gsx$party2.$t;
      resultData[i][8]=data.feed.entry[i].gsx$candidatename3.$t;
      resultData[i][9]=data.feed.entry[i].gsx$party3.$t;
    }

  });
```

How can I rewrite the above as a literal array like below

var colors = [gsx$constituency, gsx$winner2010];

I am still learning to write code so will appreciate any help

Comment: Note that `resultData[i][1]` skips the `0` index, so the length of *resultData[i]* ends up being 10 (one more than the highest index, which is 9).

Comment: It would help if you provide a sample of the data (simplified and obfuscated if necessary).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.getJSON("https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1IoNqeReOPKNFrYMlK2rnJVuMaLeAgnZneLbKYSQ7bs4/od6/public/values?alt=json", function(data) {
  var len = data.feed.entry.length;

  for (var i=0; i<len; i++) {
    //first row "title" column
    var current = data.feed.entry[i];
    resultData[i]= [current.gsx$constituency.$t, current.gsx$winner2010.$t, current.gsx$winningparty.$t, ...]; // include all here
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should update your code like below:

```
$.getJSON("https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1IoNqeReOPKNFrYMlK2rnJVuMaLeAgnZneLbKYSQ7bs4/od6/public/values?alt=json", function(data) {

    data.feed.entry.forEach(function(singleEntry) {
        var resultData = [];
        resultData.push(singleEntry);
    })

});
```

Now you can get data like *resultData[index].gsx$constituency*.

Comment: Doing this he won't be able to access the values in this 2-dimensional array manner: resultData[x][y]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to put all values in 2-dimensional array :

```
var resultData = [];
$.getJSON("https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1IoNqeReOPKNFrYMlK2rnJVuMaLeAgnZneLbKYSQ7bs4/od6/public/values?alt=json", function(data) {   
  var len = data.feed.entry.length, entries = data.feed.entry;
  for (var i=0; i<len; i++) {
     var row = [];
     for (var name in entries[i]) row.push(entries[i][name].$t);
     resultData.push(row);
  }
  console.log('result:', resultData);
});
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/5zycjq7c/

Comment: Better to replace `for (var name in entries[i])` with `Object.keys(entries[i]).map` to avoid inherited, enumerable properties. You could also replace the initial *for* loop with *forEach*. ;-)